# Rust How to pass static Lazy as a parameter

Tags: rust

I have this code to initialize the metrics registry

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

pub static REQUEST_COUNTER: Lazy<IntCounter> = Lazy::new(|| {
    register_int_counter!("requests_total", "Request counter").expect(REGISTRY_ERR)});
pub static ERROR_COUNTER: Lazy<IntCounter> = Lazy::new(|| {
    register_int_counter!("errors_total", "Error counter").expect(REGISTRY_ERR)});
...

pub fn create_registry() -> Registry {
    let registry = Registry::new();   
    registry.register(Box::new(REQUEST_COUNTER.clone())).expect(REGISTRY_ERR);
    registry.register(Box::new(ERROR_COUNTER.clone())).expect(REGISTRY_ERR);
    ...

    registry
}
```

I want to extract the repetitive part into a new function

```
pub fn create_registry() -> Registry {
    ...
    register_collector(&registry, &REQUEST_COUNTER);
    ...
    registry
}

fn register_collector <T> (registry: &Registry, collector: &Lazy<T>) where T: Collector + Clone {
    registry.register(Box::new(collector.clone())).expect(REGISTRY_ERR);
}
```

but rust compiler shows an error for this function signature:

```
   |
37 |     registry.register(Box::new(collector.clone())).expect(REGISTRY_ERR);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Collector` is not implemented for `&once_cell::sync::Lazy<T>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Collector`
```

What is the correct signature for "register_collector" function?

Comment: The final working solution from Rob

fn register_collector <T> (registry: &Registry, collector: &'static Lazy<T>) where T: Collector + Clone {  
     registry.register(Box::new((*collector).clone()))
        .expect(REGISTRY_ERR)   
}

Answer (score 2):

`register_collector` is passed a borrowed `Lazy` reference, so it needs to be dereferenced with `*`:

```
    .register(Box::new((*collector).clone()))
```